# Responsive Design in HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to make a website where I'm using an "accordian" as my design for big screen devices (>750px) and I want to use a different design (Normal Buttons) for small devices.
I have studied how to apply diff css design for different screen size but don't know what to do if even my html content is different.
Can anyone please help me with how my html syntax should be for these two different contents ?

Comment: I'm sorry, Stackoverflow is not a free coding service however, there are many, many, many tutorials on how to get started with html, css and javascript. It takes some effort and time to understand but learning it this way is well rewarding! Try to put some time into in and where you run into any problems you are always welcome to ask here.

Comment: I have done many courses online on html css and Js but none of them taught me to use responsive design for altering html content. They only taught how to use media queries for changing css content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want different  html what you can do is make 2 parts of content that are basicly the same but

```
@media screen and (min-width: 750px){
    .smallClass{
               display:none;
    {
    .bigClass{
               display:block;
    {
}
```

That way it switches between the blocks depending on your screen width

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! Hope it helps you with the rest of your project. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to adjust CSS rules to different screen sizes.

This is an example with a class named "testClass"

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px){
    .testClass{
               color: blue;
    {
}
```

Comment: Yesh but suppose I'm using two div's (One for Accordian and one for Buttons). How do I hide the buttons on large screen devices and just show the accordian, and show only the buttons on small screen devices and hide the accordian.

Comment: You can put as many rules as you want inside a media query. You can also make multiple media queries